# How to say: "the water is boiling" in Taiwanese Mandarin?

Tags: taiwan

When using an electric water cooker/boiler, how to translate the following:

> The water is boiling.

What would be arguably the most common way in Mandarin to say this in Taiwan?

Comment: "The water is boiling": 水開啦.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "The water is boiling."

We say 水開了 in Taiwan. Nothing else.

我們都說「水開了」，好像沒有人用其他講法。

Comment: Wouldn't 水開了 be the water is boiled and not the water is boiling? Wouldn't the water is boiling be something more like 水烧了 or 烧水了.

Comment: Here is one: 水滾了

Answer (score 1):

“水開了/沸了/滾了” are all used in oral. Even “水好了” goes well (好了=燒好了, and you can use it in preparing for bath, either).

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to describe water boiling, depends on the situation, say temperature or some flow within, of water.

- 水開了：water has reached at 100°C
- 水滾了: water has reached at 100°C
- 水在沸騰: water is going up to 100°C

The first one is the most common way to describe the water is boiled already.

Comment: The way you distinguish three sentences doesn’t make any sense. They’re same but different statements anyway.